# Scala remove xml element from an inner child

Tags: xml, scala, nodes

I was trying to remove a child element from a xml using Scala xml. I have spent so much time to figure out how to remove a child element but nothing works. Please help

Input XML:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header>
        <Header xmlns="http://abcde.com/reportserv">
            <RequestId>kfgndfgldfknbdfbd</RequestId>
            <ResponseTime>13.98</ResponseTime>
        </Header>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <DetailResponse xmlns="http://abcde.com/reportserv">
            <DetailResult>
                <Detail>
                    <Domain>Not Available</Domain>
                    <Name />
                    <Email />
                    <PostalCode />
                </Detail>
                <Detail>
                    <Domain>Available</Domain>
                    <Name />
                    <Email />
                    <Phone>143-234-1234</Phone>
                    <PostalCode />
                </Detail>
                <Detail>
                    <Domain>Not Available</Domain>
                    <Name />
                    <Email>tp1@gmail.com</Email>
                    <Phone />
                    <PostalCode />
                </Detail>
            </DetailResult>
        </DetailResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

From the above xml I would like to remove Email and Phone elements

Output Xml:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header>
        <Header xmlns="http://abcde.com/reportserv">
            <RequestId>kfgndfgldfknbdfbd</RequestId>
            <ResponseTime>13.98</ResponseTime>
        </Header>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <DetailResponse xmlns="http://abcde.com/reportserv">
            <DetailResult>
                <Detail>
                    <Domain>Not Available</Domain>
                    <Name />
                    <PostalCode />
                </Detail>
                <Detail>
                    <Domain>Available</Domain>
                    <Name />
                    <PostalCode />
                </Detail>
                <Detail>
                    <Domain>Not Available</Domain>
                    <Name />
                    <PostalCode />
                </Detail>
            </DetailResult>
        </DetailResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Code I tried only looks one level

```
def deleteNodes(n: Elem, f: (Node) => Boolean) = {
  n.child.foldLeft(NodeSeq.Empty)((acc, elem) => if (f(elem)) acc else acc ++ elem)
}


var deleted_elements = person.copy(child = deleteNodes(person, (elem) => (elem.label=="Email"|| elem.label=="Phone")))
```

Comment: As I see, `deleteNodes` doesn't delete their. You only select elements to delete. 
Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890457/removing-nodes-from-xml